# Should I use "with" or "regarding" in this context?

Tags: prepositions, verbs

Which one is more appropriate?

> 1. I'll contact him and I'll keep you updated **with** the arrangements status.

**or**

> 2. I'll contact him and I'll keep you updated **regarding** the arrangements status.

Which one should I use? "Regarding" or "with"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a proper preposition?

Then...

Better say-

> I'll contact him and keep you updated ***on*** the status of the arrangements.

We generally use the verb `update` in this format:

> update *<someone>* **on** <something>

Comment: Could you explain why with can't be used here? I've seen many examples where with can be used.

Comment: Of course, there could be many examples, I *never* said others are *plain wrong* and cannot be used. I just said what is *better*.

Comment: One more question can 'regarding' also be used in situations like this?

Comment: To find whether or not we can use something can be answered using Google NGram checker. This lists you books and you may rely on the results as compared to searching the phrase on *plain* Google. For example [this is the result when you search for "update regarding"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22update%20regarding%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1999,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl). However, read the sentence fully to tally whether it fits. In think for this particular usage, we can use 'update regarding' but we don't address someone directly. When you update **someone**, you use 'on'.

Comment: For example: There's an **update regarding** the latest version of software. **But**, I'll update *you* **on** the latest version of software. Got it?

Comment: thanks.. and the trick for finding the usage is really helpful.